# Ubuntu not displaying WiFi networks?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, iwlwifi, network-drive

I'm new to this whole ubuntu stuff but I really want to try it out. I decided to install 16.04 on my hp laptop, however, during the installation it did not let me connect to a wifi network. I proceeded anyways and installed it. Now in the actual installed version it will still not let me connect to any wifi network because I can't turn it on. My laptop does not have a ethernet port and I currently don't have a usb cable to directly connect to internet. I went to additional drivers and nothing shows up. I tried the lspci command to see if the system detects my network card and it does but it doesn't function. Can anyone help me to make it work? I included a picture of the command I ran

After running command of rfkill list I get:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aegfw.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Just did and included it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot. That should fix the problem.